# Mysql fulltext search not working with special characters

Tags: mysql, url, full-text-search, match

Issue: I am using the MYSQL and PHP latest versions. We are facing the issue in the MYSQL FULLTEXT search. It does not work with the special characters.

Example: In the domains table, 'name' field have the following three values:

```
1. https://www.google.com 
2. https://www.yahoo.com
3. https://www.trafe.com
```

If i am using the search term `https://www.google.com`, it will show all the above three values as result but the correct answer is `https://www.google.com.`

Query:

```
SELECT name 
FROM domains 
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('https://www.google.com*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Actual result: `https://www.google.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double quote: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (“"”) characters matches
>   only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed.

For example:

```
SELECT name 
FROM domains 
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"https://www.google.com"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Result:

```
name
https://www.google.com
```

If you really want that `*` you can search for `'"https://www.google.com*"'` (`*` is put inside the double quote).

Here is SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6458/6

Comment: Thank you. its working like a charm.
But if the field value like '2 - 9' and '+91 8525896584', those values are not getting searched.

Comment: @raj, I don't understand your problem with  '2 - 9' and '+91 8525896584'. Create new question, give proper description and example.

Comment: Hi @grzegorz-adam-kowalski, I have explained in the seperate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096544/mysql-fulltext-search-does-not-work-with-hypen-and-plus. please check and kindly advise.

Comment: I have realized that putting the `*` inside the double quotes does not work as expected in this case. For example, if you were to search for `'"https://www.google.co*"'`, you will not get any result. If you find a way to solve that, it would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @SamS, I hadn't noticed this before, but yes, special characters are all ignored. The asterisk, dots, colon and slash are all dropped. Only phrases consisting of whole words are searched for. Try `https www google` for example.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski Thank you. That did not work as expected but it helped me to find a sort of a **workaround** since using `https www google` returned all the records i.e., `1. https://www.google.com` & `2. https://www.yahoo.com` & `3. https://www.trafe.com`. I used `googl*` as the only keyword for searching and had the condition like this: `WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('googl*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` and it managed to return the desired output: `1. https://www.google.com`.