# MYSQL FULLTEXT search does not work with hypen '-' and plus '+'

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match

**Issue:** I am using the MYSQL and PHP latest versions. We are facing the issue in the MYSQL FULLTEXT search. It does not work with the hypen(-) and plus(+) characters.

**Example:1**
   In the industry table, 'industry_size' field have the following values:

```
 1. 1
 2. 2 - 9
 3. 10 - 15
```

If i am using the search term `2 - 9`, it will show the empty result but the correct answer is `2 - 9`.

**Example:2**
   In the user table, 'phone_number' field have the following values:

```
 1. 9856237845
 2. +91 8945785698
 3. +91 7489569878
```

If i am using the search term `+91 89`, it will show the empty result but the correct answer is `+91 8945785698`.

Kindly advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) says:

> The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike
>   the other operators, it should be appended to the word to be affected.
>   Words match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.

Try this:

```
MATCH(field) AGAINST("+91 89*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

or you can use Binary operator

```
where BINARY your_column = BINARY "2-9"
```

Comment: `MATCH(field) AGAINST("+91 89*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)` it will return empty result.